# MySQL Optimization - Need advices

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a CentOS 7 VM with 32 GB RAM (4 cores/8 threads) 3.4 GHz+
I ran the MySQLTuner script, and followed the recommendations that they gave, but it's still very slow

My current config in my my.cnf file is:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0

key_buffer        = 32M
max_allowed_packet    = 268435456
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 384
key_buffer_size=32G
max_connections = 1200
max_user_connections=1000
table_open_cache=3000
table_open_cache=5000
table_definition_cache=2048
sort_buffer_size=32M
join_buffer_size = 32M
read_buffer_size=32M
wait_timeout=20
read_rnd_buffer_size=786432
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M

myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_limit=8M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65535
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 8
tmp_table_size=320M
thread_concurrency=32


innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 600
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=60M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=20
innodb_table_locks=0
max_heap_table_size=128M
net_buffer_length = 16384
max_connect_errors = 10
open_files_limit=50000
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
low-priority-updates=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
concurrent_insert=ALWAYS


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d










[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size=512M
sort_buffer_size=256M
read_buffer=256M
write_buffer=256M


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet    = 16M



[isamchk]
key_buffer = 384M
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M
```

I restarted MySQL a short while ago to apply my most recent changes.

When I run the script, this is what I get:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.4.4 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[[0;32mOK[0m] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.41-MariaDB
[[0;32mOK[0m] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] Status: [0;32m+ARCHIVE [0m[0;32m+Aria [0m[0;32m+BLACKHOLE [0m[0;32m+CSV [0m[0;32m+FEDERATED [0m[0;32m+InnoDB [0m[0;32m+MRG_MYISAM [0m
[[0;34m--[0m] Data in MyISAM tables: 23M (Tables: 75)
[[0;34m--[0m] Data in InnoDB tables: 65M (Tables: 643)
[[0;34m--[0m] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[[0;34m--[0m] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 4)
[[0;31m!![0m] Total fragmented tables: 516

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[[0;32mOK[0m] There is no anonymous account in all database users
[[0;32mOK[0m] All database users have passwords assigned
[[0;31m!![0m] User 'pixoneo@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[[0;34m--[0m] There is 605 basic passwords in the list.

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] Up for: 20m 58s (877K q [697.220 qps], 52K conn, TX: 16B, RX: 195M)
[[0;34m--[0m] Reads / Writes: 96% / 4%
[[0;34m--[0m] Total buffers: 22.3G global + 4.9M per thread (1200 max threads)
[[0;31m!![0m] Maximum possible memory usage: 28.1G (89% of installed RAM)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Slow queries: 0% (9/877K)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Highest usage of available connections: 40% (483/1200)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 2.0G/773.0K
[[0;31m!![0m] Key buffer hit rate: 94.3% (53 cached / 3 reads)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Query cache efficiency: 45.6% (497K cached / 1M selects)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[[0;32mOK[0m] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 22K sorts)
[[0;31m!![0m] Joins performed without indexes: 15817
[[0;32mOK[0m] Temporary tables created on disk: 11% (23K on disk / 204K total)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (483 created / 52K connections)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Table cache hit rate: 102% (1K open / 1K opened)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Open file limit used: 23% (239/1K)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (199K immediate / 199K locks)

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] InnoDB is enabled.
[[0;34m--[0m] InnoDB BufferPool Size :20.0G
[[0;34m--[0m] InnoDB BufferPool Inst :1
[[0;32mOK[0m] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 20.0G/65.4M
[[0;31m!![0m] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[[0;32mOK[0m] InnoDB log waits: 0

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Variables to adjust:
    join_buffer_size (> 1.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=20)
```

Does anyone have any recommendations with what to do now? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> key_buffer_size=32G

NO!  You have left no room for anything else.  Are you using MyISAM?  If so, set it to 4G for your 32GB server.  If not, set it to 20M.

> Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 2.0G/773.0K

That is contradictory!  Is it 2G or is it 32G?  Do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'key_buffer_size';`.  If it says 2G, then you have not shown us the my.cnf that is being used.

> Total fragmented tables: 516

Ignore; most tables are "fragmented" most of the time.  It's not worth worrying about.

877K queries in 20 minutes?  That's rather busy.  If the slowlog is turned on, let's see what showed up in it.

483/1200 connections.  Are they forgetting to disconnect?  What else might be leading to `Max_used_connections = 483`?

> Thread cache hit rate: 99% (483 created / 52K connections)
>   table_open_cache=5000

5000 is overkill

Anyway, the real thing to look at for "slow" is the **SlowLog**:

- Set `long_query_time=1`
- Turn on the slow log
- Wait a day
- use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog
- show us the first couple of queries in that summary
- include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for those table(s) and queries